# Rolling and Mode function to get the majority of voting for rows in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Close': np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=10)})

lbound, ubound = 0, 1
change = df["Close"].diff()

df["Change"] = change
df["Result"] = np.select([ np.isclose(change, 1) | np.isclose(change, 0) | np.isclose(change, -1),
                        # The other conditions
                        (change > 0) & (change > ubound),
                        (change < 0) & (change < lbound),
                         change.between(lbound, ubound)],[0, 1, -1, 0])
```

```
      Close           Change       Result
0   54.881350           NaN          0
1   71.518937         16.637586      1
2   60.276338        -11.242599     -1
3   54.488318        -5.788019      -1
4   42.365480        -12.122838     -1
5   64.589411        22.223931       1
6   43.758721       -20.830690      -1
7   89.177300        45.418579       1
8   96.366276        7.188976        1
9   38.344152        58.022124      -1
```

Problem statement - Now, I want the majority of voting for index 1,2,3,4 assigned to index 0, index 2,3,4,5 assigned to index 1 of result columns, and so on for all the subsequent indexes.

I tried:

```
df['Voting'] = df['Result'].rolling(window = 4,min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0]).shift()
```

But,this doesn't give the result I intend. It takes the first 4 rolling window and applies the mode function.

```
     Close          Change       Result    Voting
0   54.881350        NaN            0       NaN
1   71.518937       16.637586       1       0.0
2   60.276338      -11.242599      -1       0.0
3   54.488318      -5.788019       -1      -1.0
4   42.36548       -12.122838      -1      -1.0
5   64.589411       22.223931       1      -1.0
6   43.758721      -20.830690      -1      -1.0
7   89.177300       45.418579       1      -1.0
8   96.366276       7.188976        1      -1.0
9   38.344152      -58.022124      -1       1.0
```

Result I Intend - Rolling window of 4(index 1,2,3,4) should be set and mode function be applied and result
should be assigned to index 0,then next rolling window(index 2,3,4,5) and result should
be assigned to index 1 and so on..

Comment: What happens when you have equality because 4 is even?

Comment: In my case, if they are equal I would assign 0(neutral). As I have a huge stock price data, could you please tell me how would I assign 0 in my case?

Comment: I updated my answer according my comment. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reverse your list before then shift of 1 (because you don't want the current index in the result):

```
majority = lambda x: 0 if len((m := x.mode())) > 1 else m[0]
df['Voting'] = (df[::-1].rolling(4, min_periods=1)['Result']
                        .apply(majority).shift())
print(df)

# Output
       Close     Change  Result  Voting
0  54.881350        NaN       0    -1.0
1  71.518937  16.637586       1    -1.0
2  60.276338 -11.242599      -1    -1.0
3  54.488318  -5.788019      -1     0.0
4  42.365480 -12.122838      -1     1.0
5  64.589411  22.223931       1     0.0
6  43.758721 -20.830690      -1     1.0
7  89.177300  45.418579       1     0.0
8  96.366276   7.188976       1    -1.0
9  38.344152  58.022124      -1     NaN
```

Comment: I appreciate it. Could you please explain how the above lambda function is working?

Comment: `mode` returns the most represented values. If you have only one, returns it else returns 0 because there is an equality. The walrus operator `(m := x.mode())` allow me to set the result of `mode` to `m` then use it to return the result. Without walrus operator: `0 if len(x.mode()) > 1 else x.mode()[0]`, I have to compute `mode` twice.